# Football manager like drag&drop interface

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am creating a soccer management system in PHP and Javascript (jquery) to organize teams and matches. I am now develping the match part and I would like to show to the user a drag&drop based interface to place players on the soccer field. I could write the code by myself but that would require a big effort and I'm sure that someone has already thought about this and may suggest some implementation I could use. Anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since you use jquery start here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 1):

It's not an implementation because that's difficult without all the requirements, but you might find this pretty usefull: [JqueryUI-Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: I actually know how to create such a system and my idea was to use draggable items in Jquery UI but I would have to set few contraints like the number of elements in the field, avoid overlapping items and also save the player position for future changes. These would require a lot of effort and I was seeking for someone who has already developed such a system or something similar to have a starting point and eventualy make some changes.

Comment: @Michele: Regarding saving the position, I found this: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free and popular JavaScript library (called also framework): [*jQuery*](http://jquery.com/). To create Drag&Drop use [*jQuery UI*](http://jqueryui.com/) and it's [*Draggable*](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) form, which can help you a lot. (There are examples included.)